# Dual of a bimodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, duality-theorems

For a noncommutative ring $R$, and an $R$-$R$-bimodule $B$, what is the "correct/natural" notion of its dual bimodule? I am interested, really, when $B$ is projective as a left $R$-module.